# Python3 flagging 'async def' as invalid syntax

Tags: python, server

So, I'm trying to write a bot for a discord server, using discord.py as an API wrapper. I'm trying to use my Raspberry Pi 2 B as a server to run it. I have jessie and python 3.4 installed on the device, as well as some modules for python. The imported modules in my code are discord, asyncio, and datetime. However, when I try to run my bot, which works perfectly on my mac, I get this error message:

```
File "BotTest.py", line 8
    async def on_ready():
        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For reference: this is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name, bot.user)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print([c.name for c in bot.get_all_channels()])
    print('------')

bot.run('Bot-User-Token')
```

The 'Bot-User-Token' is, of course, replaced by the actual user token in the full code. The only other part of the code is a function defined with 'async def on_message(message):', so it would be affected by the same issue.

Comment: I wrote a more in-depth answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43948477/6622817

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe async and await are for python 3.5, I think you'll need to use the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator for `async def` and `yield from` for `await` in python 3.4

Answer (score -2):

from version 3.4
asycn and await are reserved keywords

like the error in below image

[image]

copy the link up to directory/folder name( not include **init**.py)
you will get a list of .py files
[image]

rename async file to _async or asynch or anything u want as async is now a reserved keyword with us from version 3.4

once renamed than open check in all files where we have import async
modify the new name every where

and enjoy

Comment: It looks like the OP intended to use the reserved syntax in order to use `async` functions; in this case there is no clashing module as in your images. The accepted answer has the actual issue and solution here.

Answer (score -2):

You could just do `python3 <yourbot>.py` since it uses python3

edit: for this to work you need to do make sure python3 has discord.py by using `pip3 install discord-rewrite` and your code would have to be written with discord rewrite modules.

Comment: As [tobyd's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58419/58316) points out, async and await aren't supported until Python 3.5, but the question says that Python 3.4 is installed. Running `python3 <yourbot>.py` will just run the Python 3.4 version which doesn't work, unfortunately. Perhaps you could explain how to make sure you have Python 3.5 which will work?